# Data is not updated into the database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I wish to insert and update the data from the textbox.

Why my data is not updated into the database? (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio) Anyone please help me. Appreciate!

```
    //connection    

    //update 
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        sql = "Update adm SET qty = '" & txtqty.Text & "' Where xxx = '" & Trim(Session("xxx")) & "' "
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
        'conn.open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        txtqty.Text = ""

    Else
// do insert    
    crow = ds.tables("adm").newrow()

    crow("xxx") = Session("xxxx")
    crow("xxx") = Session("xxx")
    crow("xxx") = xxxxx
    crow("xxx") = xxxxx
    crow("xxxxx") = xxxxx
    crow("xxxx") = xxxxx
    crow("xxxxx") = xxxxx
    crow("xxxx") = xxxxx
    crow("xxxx") = xxxxx
    crow("qty") = trim(txtqty.text)

    ds.tables("adm").rows.add(crow)

    da.update(ds, "adm")

    lbl.Text = "<strong>Data saved! </font></strong>"

    conn.close()

End If
```

Here is the connection

```
    sql = "SELECT * FROM adm  "
    conn = New SqlConnection(ConnStr)
    cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    conn.open()
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    cb = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
    ds = New DataSet
    da.fill(ds, "adm")
    dt = ds.Tables(0)
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Also: what exactly happens? Do you get an error? If so: ***WHAT*** error? Can you show us your **connection string**, please?

Comment: @marc_s can you show me how to use parametrized queries by using the above code for me? Thanks!

Comment: If connection is ok, then show us your full "_UPDATE_" string. Maybe your WHERE clause contains something that cannot find updatable row...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **always** used parametrized queries to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities - and it's faster, too!

To use parameters, write your SQL statement like this:

```
string stmt = "Update adm SET qty = @Qty WHERE ID = @ID"
```

and then use it like this:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stmt, conn))
{        
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Qty", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 42;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 4711;

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

More resources on using **parametrized queries** in ADO.NET:

- [Shorten development time by using parameterized queries in ADO.NET](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/shorten-development-time-by-using-parameterized-queries-in-adonet/)
- [Creating a Parameterized Query in ADO.NET](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=22676)
- [Using Parameterized Query in ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20210512233418/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/092601-1.shtml)

Comment: izzit the cmd.Parameters.Add is based on how many columns I have in sql database?

Comment: @Bella: the `cmd.Parameters` is based on the **parameters** (`@Id`, `@Qty`) that you use in your query

Comment: sorry to allow me to ask one more question , how to do with this cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 4711; - I want to replace the 4711 with my ID which is retrieve from '" & Trim(Session("ID")) & "'.

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Trim(Session("ID")));`

Comment: don't know why I'm still can't get my updated data. It is any wrong with this code ? cmd.Parameters.Add("@qty", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtqty

Comment: @Bella: what is `txtqty` ??? You need to set an **integer** value - not a textbox, not a string - an **INTEGER** value

Comment: txtqty is a textbox. It will display what integer user is key in before. It also can let user do update by changing the integer inside the textbox. Now my problem is I cannot fix the integer, I want let the user key in themselves. Hope for help. Thanks